# Is it acceptable to submit manuscript to new journal if the first journal provides no response, is unreachable, and might be fake?

Tags: publications

I have submitted a paper to a journal. Having got no reply (after waiting for more than the period of acceptance) I tried to connect the editor via telephone numbers given on website. It said that the telephone number did not exist. So, I tried to open the website link, it did not open initially and later it connected me to a different site with the same name where it sold hardware parts. Hence I thought it was a fake website and applied to another journal and was accepted. Now it asks me to pay fee to publish paper. Is there any problem if I publish the paper in the second journal?

Comment: Did you tell the story about the first journal to the second journal? Also, who asks you to pay fee to publish paper? Please clarify.

Comment: Just a rough intuition: That is a fake journal and do not pay to publish, for it would do you no good...

Comment: "Never pay to publish" is good advice only in some fields, I am afraid.

Comment: "_Now it asks me to pay fee to publish paper_". Would you please clarify that who is that "it"? Who asks you to pay fee to publish paper? The first journal or the second journal?

Answer (score 8):

Based on what you describe, I would see it as exceedingly likely that the journal is indeed fake. I would formally retract the paper at the journal, and afterwards discontinue all dealings with them. They will likely not answer, but I would just assume that the entire submission is dead as soon as you have told them that you wish to retract. The will likely not publish the paper anyway, if you are not paying them a fee (which you will of course not do).

After you have retracted the submission to the first journal, there are no ethical issues with submitting the paper again, this time making sure that the journal is in fact "real". Some advise you to tell the second journal about the "history" of the paper, but I am honestly not convinced that this is ethically or practically necessary. As long as the paper is not under consideration elsewhere (and it is not, as you have retracted the original submission), the new journal does not need to know where you have tried before to get the same material published. For instance, one also does not typically indicate if a paper was rejected before at a different venue.

Comment: May I ask: how would  the OP do to contact the first journal to express the will that he wants to formally retract the paper?

Comment: @scaaahu Well, I was assuming that you still have *something* (a contact mail address, a contact form, anything). If you have indeed no way of reaching the old journal, I would just assume that the entire thing stopped operating by now.

Comment: I know what you mean. I am still dubious. I am not a lawyer. I don't know how can you legally claim that you have formally retracted the paper?

Comment: @scaaahu I don't think that this is a legal question. Legally, as long as you have not signed the copyright slip, the journal *cannot* go forward and publish the paper. It is more a question of publishing ethics re: double submission, and in this sense I think you should be ok as long as you made due effort to retract from the first journal.

Comment: Okay, I am satisfied with your explanation about legal issue. I am still unclear about how would the OP claim that he has made due effort to retract the paper. For example, what if the first journal did not disappear, just that they changed the name/phone number and web site? How would the OP claim that he has done everything possible to track them down? Sorry that I may sound very pushy(I don't know the right word to describe it). In my opinion, it's a tough  issue. Or, am I thinking too much?

Comment: @scaaahu You're thinking about it too much.

Comment: @scaaahu, they got in contact to demand payment, all he need do is respond to that contact that he is withdrawing the paper. That's it. It would have been better if he had done so before he submitted elsewhere, but this seems like a bit of a special circumstance. The first journal basically disappeared. You're not required to wait forever while and allow a journal to hold your article hostage.